# What is a good resistance value for voltage divider to measure LiPo voltage with Arduino

Tags: arduino, resistors, voltage-divider, lipo

(Full disclosure: I'm a newbie.)

I'm trying to measure my 4S lipo's cell voltages using an Arduino Mega. I know that I should use a voltage divider (actually, several of them) and I think I understand how it works. I also know about the voltage difference relative to GND would increase by up to 4.2V for each cell, and at 4th cell, it can be over 16V so I should be safely dividing it down to max 5V. However, I'm confused with what resistance values should I use for the divider(s). Wouldn't a low resistance value mean effectively shorting the lipo? Would a too high resistance value cause incorrect readings? In this context, what is a "low" resistance value and what is a "high" resistance value? Or are all resistors already way above that limit and I can use them safely? I've got all types of resistors from 47R to 1M, but I don't know what to use.

Comment: Make it small enough to not be influenced by the measurements devices input impedance, make it large enough to not draw too much current.

Comment: @PlasmaHH how do I determine that? e.g. is 1K okay, or is 470K okay?

Comment: That obviously depends on the input impedance, and your judgement of "too much current" and "not be influenced too much", all of which we have no idea about.

Comment: @PlasmaHH well, the battery will be flying a quadcopter (and powering the arduino and a few electronic components, but they are all negligible compared to the ESCs' current draw). they will be dividing 16.8 volts at max, and it should draw as less current as possible to measure with ~0.1V accuracy.

Comment: Without looking up the data sheet - if you don't mind needing to disconnect it when not in use - ie on the load side of the on/off switch or break plug, then a total of 10k-20k range will be very safe. If Full scale is say 20V then you want a 4:1 divider to 5V so 3R:R so say 15k Bat to ARduino and 4k& Arduino to ground. You could use a pot for part of that OR adjust in software or trim with parallel resistors. || Odds are you can go to 50k or even 100k and be not too inaccurate but lower is better. Arduino uP will have   an ADC Rinmax spec somewhere. At 20 V and 10 =bits = 1024:1 divide you...

Comment: ... get about 20 mV per bit so accuracy of about 0.1V allows 1+ bits of error. Error is caused both by Verror = Rin x (Ibias + Ioffset) PLUS by time constant issues where input c takes time to charge and if R is too large the cap will not be charged enough by next ADC samople time.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon great explanation, exactly what I was needing. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon and lastly, what if I can't disconnect it?

Comment: Ibat ~= Vbat/Rdiv. Assume say 16V and 20k =~~ 0.8 mA. That eats about 20 mAh/day or 140 mAh/week. Depending on battery size and time and depth of discharge in use that will or won't matter. 20 mAh will usually be bearable, 140 usually not. Std methodis use highest resistors that work and then use HIGH side switch to disconnect. This MUST be a pchannel fet or pnp transistor disconnecting the Vin + connection. Disconnecting the bottom stops flow to ground BUT uP ping is pulled to ~= Vbat+ - usually fatal.....

Comment: ...  You also can use an opamp buffer that can tolerate very high Rin. At say 1M the drain usually does not matter over usual time periods. || (Past bed time in NZ . 4:15am and I have to be up at 8:15 so ... TTFN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't a low resistance value mean effectively shorting the lipo?
>   Would a too high resistance value cause incorrect readings?

You are absolutely correct so, some people use a low value potential divider (in order to obtain decent accuracy) but disconnect this potential divider from the LiPo when not requiring a measurement. In effect, the low duty cycle measurement dramatically increases the effective resistance of the potential divider.

You can disconnect the potential divider with a P channel MOSFET and a BJT - the BJT is activated from a spare IO line. I'm not saying this suits your application of course.

Comment: Thanks, I think it would be an overkill, but I've got the idea. I don't have a MOSFET but I've got many simple NPN transistors, I think I can use them too in order to get the same effect. Lastly, if I don't do it and go straight, what would be a good resistance value?

Comment: You need to check the data sheet of the Arduino, specifically the ADC input - it may be high impedance buffered allowing you to have circa 100k resistor values OR it might specify something like the maximum source impedance to achieve a certain accuracy. ADC input pin bias currents are also very relevant to this too.

Comment: Okay, I'll be looking into that, thanks for the detailed explanation.